# How to read ONLY 1 word in python?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, text-files

I've created an empty text file, and saved some stuff to it. This is what I saved:

```
 Saish ddd TestUser ForTestUse
```

There is a space before these words. Anyways, I wanted to know how to read only 1 WORD in the text file using python. This is the code I used:

```
#Uncommenting the line below the line does literally nothing.

import time
#import mmap, re

print("Loading Data...")
time.sleep(2)

with open("User_Data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read() ##Assume the sample file has 3 lines
    first = lines.split(None, 1)[0]

print(first)


print("Type user number 1 - 4 for using different user.")
ans = input('Is the name above correct?(y/1 - 4) ')
if ans == 'y':
    print("Ok! You will be called", first)
    
elif ans == '1':
    print("You are already registered to", first)
    
elif ans == '2':
    print('Switching to accounts...')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    with open("User_Data.txt") as f:
        lines = f.read() ##Assume the sample file has 3 lines
        second = lines.split(None, 2)[2]

    print(second)
    #Fix the passord issue! Very important as this is SECURITY!!!
```

when I run the code, my output is:

```
Loading Data...
Saish
Type user number 1 - 4 for using different user.
Is the name above correct?(y/1 - 4) 2
Switching to accounts...
TestUser ForTestUse
```

as you can see, it diplays both "TestUser" and "ForTestUse" while I only want it to display "TestUser".

Comment: The same way you read only one line: You read _more_ than one line, then ignore the extra. (Strictly, `readline()` doesn't completely throw away the extra -- it just puts it in a buffer to use later when the user asks to read more content -- but the point is the same: You can't ask the operating system to read one word or one line, so you need to either read one byte at a time until you get to a word separator or line separator, or just read a bigger chunk and pay attention to only the subset you actually care about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give a limit to `split()`, all the items from that limit to the end are combined. So if you do

```
lines = 'Saish ddd TestUser ForTestUse'
split = lines.split(None, 2)
```

the result is

```
['Saish', 'ddd', 'TestUser ForTestUse']
```

If you just want the third word, don't give a limit to `split()`.

```
second = lines.split()[2]
```

Comment: But when I put:

`third = lines.split()[4]`

It gave me an error:
    `third = lines.split()[4]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: There are only 4 words, so the highest index is 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use it directly without passing any None

```
lines.split()[2]
```

I understand your passing (None, 2) because you want to get None if there is no value at index 2,
A simple way to check if the index is available in the list

Python 2

```
2 in zip(*enumerate(lines.split()))[0]
```

Python 3

```
2 in list(zip(*enumerate(lines.split())))[0]
```